# Using boolean to state true or false to duplicated words without using a loop construct

Tags: java

```
public class Main                                       
{                                       
  public static void main(String[] args)                                        
  {                                                                             
    String[] find2 = {"cool","NOT","NOT,"Cool"};                                        
    String[] nofind = {"Fly","poke","ok";                                           
    System.out.println(Test.out(find);                                      
    System.out.println(Test.out(nofind));                                                                           
  }                                     
}
```

+

```
public class Test                                   
{
public static boolean Out(String[] input) {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
                if (input[i].equals(input[j]) && i != j) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I've managed to function a code that tells me if it is true or false if there is repeated series of word in the string array, however, how can I achieve this without a loop construct that also finds upper and lower case dupes?

Comment: How would you expect to find duplicates *without* iterating when you're working with arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Using a `Map<String, Integer>` which would have words from list/array of strings as keys (lowercase words) should solve your problem. If the new word is already present (check new words by using `toLowercase()`) in the map then you can return true.

You would have to traverse the list or array of strings at least once (if not `for-loop` then `for-each` loop) either explicitly or implicitly(Java8 hidden loops or other collection’s constructors) to find if any words are repeated.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you cannot do this without *any* loops. However, if you are looking for *hidden* loops, you can use this:

```
public static boolean out(String[] input) {
    return input.length != new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(input)).size();
}
```

If you need to ignore case, then:

```
public static boolean out(String[] input) {
    return input.length != Arrays.stream(input).map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toSet()).size();
}
```

Comment: I am actually interested in how the first method works, Mind explaining? :)

Comment: @SamzSakerz A `Set` guarantees that there is no duplicates (duplicates are not added in). So a difference in the number of elements in the array and set would mean that there was a duplicate somewhere. And I found a typo :(

Comment: Ah I know Sets can't include duplicates like Maps but never thought about using it like that